# html の select タグで表示するリストが画面外にいった場合に画面内に移動させる方法

Tags: html, css

以下の画像のようにselectタグでリスト表示すると画面外（ブラウザの外）にリストが表示されてしまいます。
[image: 画面外]

そこで質問なのですが、
(1) 以下の画像のように画面内に自動で移動させることは可能でしょうか？
(2) 以下の画像のようにselectタグ右側起点でリストを表示するようにすることは可能でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ソースは以下の通りです。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    select {
      width: 100px;
    }
    .container {
      text-align: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <select id="my-select">
      <option value="1">Option 1111111111111111</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2222222222222222</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3333333333333333</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4444444444444444</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: width の指定を選択肢の文字が収まるよう、もう少し大きな値を指定するのが手っ取り早そうですが、それではNGなのでしょうか。

Comment: 実際に使用する場合、画面構成がもう少し複雑で、どうしても幅が広げられない状態です。別案としてはリスト内を改行できるようにすることも検討したのですが、リストを画面内に移動させるほうが都合がよい状態です。
また、本件が css や js で対応可能なのかも知りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECTタグにdir="rtl"を付けてあげてみてください。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    select {
      width: 100px;
    }
    .container {
      text-align: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <select id="my-select" dir="rtl">
      <option value="1">Option 1111111111111111</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2222222222222222</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3333333333333333</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4444444444444444</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```